# Granger Causality vs. Forecasting

Tags: forecasting, granger-causality

I am trying to explain Granger Causality to my coworkers and have this question. Granger causality tells you that variable $X$ provides helpful information about future values of $Y$, but that is what can also be inferred from any forecasting model. In your forecasting model if $X$ is significant and included in the model then that means $X$ provides helpful information about future values of $Y$. So what is delivered extra in the Granger causality model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Granger causality tells you that variable $X$ provides helpful information about future values of $Y$ <...>

The devil is in the details. Granger causality considers the *incremental* benefits on forecasting $Y$ due to using the history of $X$ *extra* to using the history of $Y$ alone. That is, the benchmark forecast is based on past values of $Y$ alone while the challenger forecast uses the past values of $X$ in addition. Meanwhile, if past values of $Y$ are excluded when making the prediction (which may or may not be the case based on the excerpt cited above) and $X$ helps predict $Y$, we cannot say much about Granger causality.

---

Here is Definition 1 from p. 428 of Granger's original paper ["Investigating causal relations by econometric models and cross-spectral methods"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912791?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1969):

> Let $U_t$ be all the information in the universe accumulated since time $t-1$ and let $U_t-Y_t$ denote all this information apart from the specified series $Y_t$.
>
> Definition 1: *Causality.* If $\sigma^2(X|U)<\sigma^2(X|\overline{U-Y})$, we say that $Y$ is causing $X$, denoted by $Y_t \rightarrow X_t$. We say that $Y_t$ is causing $X_t$ if we are better able to predict $X_t$ using all available information than if the information apart from $Y_t$ had been used.

Answer (score 4):

*Granger* causality is a weak form of causal inference, particularly when compared with *Pearl*-type causality and Bayesian networks. Forecasts, on the other hand, make no assumptions about possible causal relationships and, given that, demonstrate *association* for the purposes of prediction.

Comment: "Granger causality is a weak form of causal inference, particularly when compared with Pearl-type causality and Bayesian networks." No. As said here by Alecos Papadopoulos: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376909/is-granger-causality-still-relevant ""Granger causality" has nothing to do with causality". In fact Granger causality is exactly a particular type of forecasting tool. If you want I can give a couple of relevant reference about that.