# Can I use Granger causality to determine if the high prices in stock exchange data are affecting the closing prices?

Tags: time-series, causality, granger-causality

I am looking for an algorithm that can show whether the features in a time series data have any causal relationship. Can we use Granger causality to determine causal relationship in a multivariate time series data?

Comment: Causality is complicated. Granger-pseudocausality is, in itself, not sufficient to determine causative relations

Comment: @Firebug, I wonder if *causal* would not be more appropriate than *causative* in the sentence above (since you are talking about relationships)?

Comment: Granger causality isn't causality in any formal sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use Granger causality to determine causal relationship in a multivariate time series data?

No. Granger causality is about predictive performance, not causality. For the semantics, see
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/377569/28746 and
https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/3056/61

Comment: Thanks! Can you point to any other technique that can be used for determining causal relationship in a time series data?

Comment: @MFarhan Causality is complicated and, in general, cannot be determined from observational data alone