# Can granger testing help to predict? what is the difference between the task of prediction and the task of determine casuality

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, granger-causality

Hi I have two time series $A_t$ and $B_t$, and I want to use the past values of $A_t$ where $t=1,...,T$ to predict $B_t$ where $t=T+1$.

To do this, at first I looked for spearman correlation, if the value of $A_t$ goes down then I infer that $B_t$ will goes down as well. But I found that the causality can not be inferred from correlation. Thus I stepped into casual inference. But what I found in the posts (which I include them in the down below) here is that we can not infer causality from data using any statistical technique and we have to do an experience to test this. I am very confused of this. If so, then what Granger testing for?

Here are some related materials:

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Any_recommended_techniques_for_testing_causal_relations

https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_test_for_causation

[Granger Causality vs. Forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205023/granger-causality-vs-forecasting)

Comment: Granger causality has nothing to do with causality and is of very limited use for forecasting. Forecasting does not require any causal model, it only requires out-of-sample testing for forecast performance (not in-sample hypothesis tests like GC).

Answer (score 1):

Casuality and prediction are different concepts. Sometimes examples are helpful.

Smoking causes disease $x$. Alcoholism does not cause disease $x$. But smokers are more likely to drink alcohol. So alcoholism is a perfectly valid *predictor* of $x$, in that people who drink alcohol are more likely to get $x$ (because they're more likely to smoke). If you use alcohol to predict $x$, you will do better than random chance. But there is no direct *causation*.

Determining causal effects from observational data is difficult and sometimes requires pretty specific data structures. I'd look into instrumental variable analysis if you're interested in statistical methods for causal inference. There's also a very good book on causal inference available here which covers the topic in more formal notation https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2020/02/ci_hernanrobins_21feb20.pdf

As for which one you want, that depends on your question. If I'm working on predicting who gets a disease, a predictor that doesn't have any biological meaning is fine, as long as it reliably predicts. If I'm working on developing an intervention, I need to know if it actually does anything. No point giving up alcohol and carrying smoking if you want to decrease your chance of $x$.