# ARMA models and predictive learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima, predictive-models, prediction

It is well known that, in Time Series, *ARMA models* was proposed for make forecast about some $y_t$ based on past values of the process itself.

However this is not the only possible way for make forecast about some target variable $y_t$. Indeed is possible that past values of other process like $x_t$ can help. Indeed the concept of Granger causality (Granger predictability would be a better name) consider precisely this possibility.

Now limiting our interest into stationary time series (wide sense stationary) we can consider all above as special case of standard linear regression analysis. Indeed we can reduce ARMAs to a pure autoregressive representations too.

Moreover, also in *predictive learning* literature is common to use *linear regression* for make forecast. In this literature is common to consider many predictors, not only past values of the target variable. In order to select the best subset of predictors the *selection criteria* matters (for instance: BIC, AIC, sequential hypothesis testing, LASSO). Strategies like these follow the Granger predictability idea.

Now, in: *A Guide to Modern Econometrics* – Verbeek; Wiley (2017). ARMA models are presented. However at Par 8.12: *What about Multivariate Models?* is argued that in economics most series are related. For example we can have

$y_t = \beta x_t + \epsilon_t$

but if $x_t$ is representable as an ARMA process, then $y_t$ has an ARMA representation too (sum of ARMAs is ARMA). Author said: “*Thus, the fact that two variables are related does not imply that a pure times series approach is invalid.*”.

Now, **it seems me** that this story can be extended for many variables where for each of them something like follows hold

$y_t = X_t ' \beta + \epsilon_t$

where $ X_t $ is a vector of variables at time “t”, but any $y_t$ maintain his ARMA representation. Better, **not only** $y_t$ **maintain** his ARMA representation **but it come from relations with** $X_t$ or, at least, **match with them**.

However if this story hold, from ARMA theory, we can stay focused only on ACF and PACF of $y_t$; we can forget any other potential predictors. We can skip the $X_t$ part. Granger predictability cannot work. Common practice of predictive learning become a waste of time!

So, them seems me to strong conclusions. However, at logic level, I don't find mistakes. What go wrong above?

**Note**: interesting to note that in machine learning literature ARMA models are not considered so much; for example in the very common manual: *The Elements of Statistical Learning, Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction* -  Hastie Tibshirani Friedman; Springer (2008); ARMA models are completely not mentioned. Conversely in Time Series literature the common tools in predictive learning, as stepwise selection with some criteria, are not considered and most pages are spent in ARMA process and related concepts. For example we can see in: *Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting* - Brockwell and Davis; Springer (2016).

Comment: Hi: I'm not sure what you're asking but think of a VAR. That has selection criteria ( how many lags ? ) and it's a time series model and it's used for prediction and one can use granger causaility in the VAR framework.

Comment: So the question is "since most economic time series are related can we use simple ARMA instead of VARMA models?"? If so, then it depends: VAR models consider multiple variables and can be reformulated as VECM if there is cointegration, in order to model (economic) equilibria between variables and short-term deviations. On the other hand, VAR has large estimation error due to large number of parameters, which very often offsets its advantages. Regarding your note: machine learning excels with non-linear relations while "standard" econometric models (lasso, ARMA etc) best work if they're linear.

Comment: Even if several predictors are potentially involved, I spoke precisely of univariate models only. No systems, no VAR. We can read all above as something like a race between: pure ARMA against linear regression with all (lagged) predictors we want. Based on ref I cited seems me that the second strategy boils down to the first (ARMA). It is so?

Comment: @PaulG, I excluded integrated variables for simplicity.

Comment: I modified a bit the explanation for clarify my point.

Comment: I would argue that there often isn't that much of a difference between a regression model with lagged dependent variables ( and alternative error structures ) and an ARIMA model. If you can get your hands on Andrew Harvey's "economic analysis of time series", he has a few chapters on difference equations, distributed lags, transfer response etc and he makes connections between the two approaches. Think of the koyck distributed lag. That's an ARDL that can be re-written as a regression model with possibly not iid error structure. So, I think what you say or Verbeek said is true.

Comment: @markowitz: ah, so the question is basically "simple AR model vs a single row of a VAR model". Then, if interest is in only a single variable of the whole VAR process and since VAR models can be estimated row-wise via separate OLS regressions, sure you can ignore the other regressions. You would lose features such as Granger and instantaneous causality though. Doesn't mean VAR theory is useless, rather only choosing the right model for the specific task.

Comment: @mlofton; Thanks for the ref you give, maybe in the future I can read it. About ADL model, actually these are strongly related to my question.  However Verbeek introduce them more as a tool for policy evaluation than forecasting one. Moreover, you introduce the possibility of not iid resid. Limiting ourselves on standard linear models we can speak about standard white noise as resid. Now, it seems me that WN resid are needed for best ARMA and/or best forecasting specifications in general.

Comment: So, let me say “my hypothesis”, or better, what I understand from Verbeek suggestions, tell us that ADL cannot beat ARMA for forecasting even if them can help for other scope. It is so?

Comment: @PaulG; you sad: “..so the question is basically "simple AR model vs a single row of a VAR model".”. Yes it seems me another well posed perspective. After “ You would lose features such as Granger and instantaneous causality though. Doesn't mean VAR theory is useless, rather only choosing the right model for the specific task” the task is pure forecasting. Granger causality is a forecast tool. From above (read my coment at mlofton also) It seems me that if our ARMA is well specified there is no room for Granger causality. It is so?

Comment: Granger causality is a structural property of a VAR model, i.e. it is inspected after the model is estimated, so it is not part of forecast in itself. In a VAR setting, Granger causality is defined only between pairs of 1 variable in the model vs all others, i.e. vector X of all variables that are not Y does not Granger-cause Y only if all parameters in the equation of Y concerning X are 0, e.g: $Y_t = b_0 + b_1*X_{t-1} + b_2*X_{t-2} + b3*Y_{t-1} + e_t $ where $b_1=b_2=0$. So in this setting the equation of $Y_t$ is reduced to an AR model, which would be sufficient for Y in this special case.

Comment: I able to test for Granger causality. You said “Granger causality is a structural property of a VAR model” I’m not sure what you mean. If you intend that GC result depend of specifications I agree. But GC remain pure correlational concept. In your example if $b_1$ and/or $b_2$ are not zero it mean that corr work. Said that, from all above my guess is that if GC appear it is because not enough lags of $Y_t$ are added in the specification at hand.

Comment: I believe we have different understandings of what Granger causality means. It is a structural concept in the sense that it helps in understanding the *relations* between variables *after* the model was estimated. It is a way to *interpret* the VAR model. It has nothing to do with forecasting. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcsTL.png) you can see this in the table of contents from Lütkepohl 2005, New Intro to Multiple TSA (Granger causality is separate from forecasting). I only brought it up because, if you do ARMA, you obviously can't check for it so you lose this interpretation.

Comment: The concept of Granger causality has produced enough problem yet. According to Stock and Watson I prefer “Granger predictability”. Therefore, without going to details, probably I disagree to your and Lütkepohl view. For me GC is a pure correlational concept, then is good for forecasting. No more. The replies of Richard Hardy and Alecos Papadopoulos: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205023/granger-causality-vs-forecasting and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376909/is-granger-causality-still-relevant
match with my view.

Comment: @markowitz: I don't think statements like ARDL can't beat ARIMA are legit because each case is different. As far as the iid issue, I don't think of ARIMA as iid error because  the MA terms are  iid but they cause successive observations to be correlated. Definitely try to get Harvey because I can't do  topic justice here but he does the best justice that I have seen. His writing style is unique because it's so terse so each page is packed with info which made it somewhat of a difficult read, atleast for me. But, after reading it a few times, I started to appreciate just how great the book is.

Comment: @mlofton; I do not find precisely the title you give. This is the book you speak about? https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/time-series-models-second-edition

Comment: @markowitz. No, that's not it. He's written three all with that same terse style but all good. Let me send you the link because that book you found is not related to your question.

Comment: @markowtiz: This is it. I don't know what you're used to but, for me, his style is unusual. But, if you read it slowly and carefully and have a problem to apply it to, it's excellent but maybe not right away. I would start from the beginning because he refers backward a lot and also uses confusing equation numbering.  https://www.amazon.com/Econometric-Analysis-Time-Economics-Handbooks/dp/026208189X/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=harvey+economic+time+series+analysis&qid=1606242095&sr=8-3